# Flask (connexion) app not reloading monitored extra_files when building app as a python package

Tags: python, flask, package, watchdog, connexion

I have a python flask (using connexion) project that I need to reload if I change any of the files in the project.
This project is built into a python module using `setup.py`, then run.
I tried using `extra_files` parameter when running the project but this does not help. I could not tell if the extra_files cared about relative path, so I designed my code to provide full paths for all files. It still does not work.

I build the module with `pip install -e .`, then run it `python -m thing.app.main`
But the module does not pick up on changes. I thought using links (using the `-e` editable) parameter would help but it does not.

I should also mention that I am running all this in my pyenv, so the paths that are run during run time maybe different as they are in the pyenv path. Is that a problem?

Is this expected? Is there a way I can use extra_files? or will I need to use a watchdog daemon to monitor file changes?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

- I did not understand that Flask watchdog process already monitors all .py files in the project. I stopped trying to send it all .py files again with extra _files. I only sent my yaml/yml config files as extra_files.
- Has nothing to do with it being a module or running locally.
- Flask was actually reloading the files properly, however it was stopping after first reload. The main problem was the `max_user_watches` setting in inotify. I changed it with `echo 524288 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` and now it works fine.